# How to hide open-api spec for one route using loopback 4

Tags: node.js, typescript, loopback, openapi, loopback4

Is there a way in Loopback 4 to use the `@get()` decorator (or any another one), passing the path but not generating the open api spec for this route?
By passing a special param / using the `@operation` or anything?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an undocumented spec option `'x-visibility': 'undocumented'` for the operation decorators `@get`, `@post`, etc. which might fit your needs. Here is an simplified example:

```
@get('/test', {
  responses: {},
  'x-visibility': 'undocumented',
})
async test() {
  // business logic
}
```

Here are some references where it is used:

- [rest.server.open-api-spec.unit.ts#L149](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/237efc93236476b2e364e6a92cd378e045ae4546/packages/rest/src/__tests__/unit/rest.server/rest.server.open-api-spec.unit.ts#L149)
- [uml.controller.ts#L23](https://github.com/derdeka/loopback4-extensions/blob/9d2ac1d877e2f8955a6bbcd9c9af3ec485f62d2e/packages/nomnoml/src/controllers/uml.controller.ts#L23)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread, but I came across it in a search and discovered there is a different (better?) way to handle this situation. The @loopback/rest import grants access to 2 objects that can achieve what OP requires. *oas* and *visibility*

```js
import { get, oas, visibility } from '@loopback/rest';

//method using oas
@get('/test')
@oas.visibility(OperationVisibility.UNDOCUMENTED)
@response(200, {
    description: 'Whatever the test is',
    content: {'application/json': {schema: TestSchema}},
  })
async test() {
  //code
}

//method using visibility
@get('/test2')
@visibility(OperationVisibility.UNDOCUMENTED)
@response(200, {
    description: 'Whatever the test2 is',
    content: {'application/json': {schema: TestSchema2}},
  })
async test2() {
  //code
}
```

You can actually use the oas namespace for your whole API spec if you wanted to as it encompasses all of the OpenApi decorators needed

Documentation:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Decorators_openapi.html#shortcuts-for-the-openapi-spec-oas-objects

Source:
https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/blob/44f2fcd827c4601ec44828c5b5f76f2f6730424e/packages/openapi-v3/src/decorators/index.ts#L24